# Why is IntelliJ stuck on Resolving Dependencies for my project?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, dependencies, pom.xml, intellij-13

IntelliJ stucked on Resolving Dependencies for PROJECT_NAME

It used to be quite fast and worked seemingly fine, but suddenly my already opened projects began giving errors in the pom.xml such as dependency not found, and whenever I reloaded the project it gets stuck on Processing build files for dependencies analysis or Resolving Dependencies for PROJECT_NAME.
It has taken up to 38 minutes one time and it still didn't complete the background task. I also searched VM options for importer as I read somewhere it could speed up things but the reality is that nothing is very clear on the subject.
My current version of IntelliJ is the 2023.1.1

Comment: please share intellij logs

Comment: The only log I get is on the bottom right I get a progress bar saying Resolving dependencies of [the name of my project]. There is no output on the console, just a background progress, that even when I try to cancel it doesn't stop as such. I could make a screenshot but is that.

Comment: search on google how to obtain intellij logs

Comment: I found that logs can be shown when it is running or debugging, but I'm just writing a dependency in the pom.xml and saving it and when reloading the maven project it is stuck on resolving dependencies

Comment: I'd recommend you contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new and share the IDE logs. (IDE main menu | Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)